# Developing GIS in MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, gis, worldwind

I am trying to develop a a rich client that shows a map using Worldwind java -
and I want to display a lot of information, icons, etc. on the map -
so I decided to use Worldwind java in MVC pattern (Model-View-Controller)

Does anyone know a good library that would support MVC pattern for GIS application?
What I am looking for in this library for example:
-manage which information is currently displayed on the map
-manage which information should be displayed on the map in case of a move on the map

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest Eclipse Modeling Framowork (EMF). You define your model (via annotated java interfaces or XML Schema or UML Diagrams...), EMF is able to generate some views and controllers (e.g. for a tree viewer) just out of the box. And WorldWind views and controllers you write yourself.